# Unity: Loading image from URL failed

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I am loading image from script to texture from URL. It is loading successfully, but the image is not reflecting on the texture.[image: The Image describes the situation]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you should  **UV unwrapped** your model(that you want to put your image on it as a texture) you save the uv and then import it to unity then you can apply texture to it , [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obB9T3jXlak) is tutorial that will show you how to do it in blender

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if I'm gathering from the image correctly, it looks like you're using NGUI. If so, then you don't use Mesh Renderer. It's been a little bit since I used NGUI, but you need a reference to the game object or to the UITexture component that is on the game object. So I'll provide some code samples below for both scenarios. But you don't use a mesh renderer unless you're wrapping the texture around a 3D model. If this is for the UITexture then you would attach the image on there.

Game Object Reference:

```
imageObject.GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = textureToUse;
```

UITexture Reference:

```
uiTextureReference.mainTexture = textureToUse;
```

I think that is what you were looking for, otherwise you need to do unwrapping and what not.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy if you are using NGUI.

1. Create a UITexture.
2. Refer it in you class either by declaring it public variable of getting it at runtime.
3. Import MiniJSON class that is easily available on internet. (Do not hesitate if you failed to find MiniJSON.Json, it could be MiniJSON.Deserialize or only Json.Deseiralize)
4. Following is the code snippet to get Facebook Display Picture with User_API_ID

   ```
   string myImageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+API_ID+"/picture?type=large&redirect=0";
               WWW myImageGraphRequest = new WWW(myImageUrl);
               yield return myImageGraphRequest;

               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myImageGraphRequest.error))
                   Debug.Log("Could not fetch own User Image due to: " + myImageGraphRequest.error);
               else
               {
                   var myImageData = MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize (myImageGraphRequest.text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
                   var myImageLinkWithData = myImageData["data"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                   string myImageLink = (string)myImageLinkWithData["url"];

                   WWW myImageRequest = new WWW(myImageLink);
                   yield return myImageRequest;

                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myImageRequest.error))
                       Debug.Log("Could not get user facebook image: " + myImageRequest.error);
                   else
                   {
                       userDP.mainTexture = myImageRequest.texture;
                   }
               }
   ```

userDP is your UITexture.